# Mozilla designMode and setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, firefox, settimeout

When I set the `designMode="On"` on the current page I can not start a `setTimout()`. Is designMode restricted to iframes only or why does this not work? The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.designMode) at MDN is not very helpful...

I want to capture the paste event anywhere on the page, not only on a single element or input field.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/powtac/qjg7K/)

Comment: Just a note.. it is not just Mozilla.. All browsers with the exception of chrome behave the same way..

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put a single element in your document, and set its `contentEditable` to true ?

This way you do not mess with the whole document..

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qjg7K/1/

---

Looking at IEs documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx they state

> **Remarks**
>
> You cannot execute script when the value of the `designMode` property is set to `On`.

---

**Update**

To be notified of any paste event in the page you can bind the listener to the document.  (*the event will bubble to the document eventually so you will always receive it..*)

I understand that you want to handle the `paste` event even when you are not inside elements that support it by default..

You can make the `body` to be `contentEditable`.. It should provide the same functionality as setting the document's `designMode` to `on`

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/f6xSt/

Comment: Where did you find this "Remarks"? And I extended my question.

Comment: @powtac, at the right side of the page i linked to (*at msdn*) it says with blue letters **Remarks**. The first line is the one i quoted..

Comment: Ah! `contentEditable != designMode`?! So catching paste and acually allowing pasting everywhere works together with JS when using `contentEditable`?

Answer (score 1):

Turning on editing for a document disables script execution in that document in most browsers.  Otherwise things would get pretty weird as you edit the `<script>` tags....

Comment: But where is this documented?

Comment: Does the thread at http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2011Jun/0462.html count?  I'm not sure it's documented in any sort of "user-facing" documentation yet.